# Effectively calculate function

Tags: algorithm

Given

```
f(n) = 1+x+x^2+x^3+……+x^n, (n >=0 && n is a integer)
```

input x, n, how can we work out the result with a greater efficiency?

Comment: This question should probably be posted on code review

Comment: Do you mean that this question should not tagged as algorithm?

Comment: No, I mean this is not a broken piece of code that you want to fix, this is a working piece of code you want to make work better

Comment: By "code review", he means http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you, I'm new here and not a native speaker. Thanks for your help. @pang,@james Massey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series). Noting that

```
(x-1)f(n) = x^{n+1}-1
```

you get

```
f(n)=(x^{n+1}-1)/(x-1).
```

Comment: Except that when `x=1`, the answer should be `f(n) = n` (instead of `0 / 0`).

Comment: @Pang `f(n) = n+1` when `x=1`

Answer (score 1):

This does `n` multiplies and `n` increments. It's easy to put the sum into closed form, but computing the closed form requires evaluating `xn+1`, which could also end up doing `n` multiplies, but doesn't require a divide.

Although this is actually valid C, think of it as pseudocode. A real implementation would check for negative `n` rather than looping through half the `int` numberspace. If you needed to apply this to an integer `x` rather than a floating point `x`, this would definitely be the way to go.

```
double polysum(int n, double x) {
  double a = 1;
  while (n--) a = x * a + 1;
  return a;
}
```

Comment: I've moved my question [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62716/effectively-calculate-the-result-of-geometric-series). It is a little different now, please take a look. Thank you all.@rici,@Pang,@ankur-singhal,@James Massey

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x = 2, n = 10;
        Double sum = new Double(0);
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= n ; i++) {
            sum = sum + Math.pow(x, i);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```